# transform a data structure from an object of arrays to an array

Tags: javascript, node-red

I have forgotten most of what I learnt so treat ma as a novice. :(

I have an object of arrays returned from a database select statement as below :-

```js
options:[{"breed":"bulldog"},{"breed":"labrador"}{"breed":"beagle"},{"breed":"dobermann"}]
```

Using javascript, how can I transpose this into an array as below :-

```
const breed ["bulldog","labrador","beagle","dobermann"];
```

The array will be used to populate a node-red dropdown menu.

Thanks for looking or advising.

I have tried split and map, but I cant seem to arrive at my required.
Maybe because I did not code it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) over the array, and then select the `breed` key of each object.

```js
const options = [{"breed":"bulldog"},{"breed":"labrador"},{"breed":"beagle"},{"breed":"dobermann"}];
const breeds = options.map(o => o.breed);

console.log(breeds);
```

---

If you can't use a hard-coded `breed` key, you can use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) with [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const options = [{"breed":"bulldog"},{"breed":"labrador"},{"breed":"beagle"},{"breed":"dobermann"}];
const breeds = options.flatMap(o => Object.values(o));

console.log(breeds);
```

Comment: Thank you. Both versions worked like a charm. :)

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped! (The green checkmark)

Answer (score -1):

```
    const obj = {options:[{"breed":"bulldog"},{"breed":"labrador"},{"breed":"beagle"},{"breed":"dobermann"}]}
    const array =[];

    obj.options.forEach((item) => {
        array.push(item.breed);
    })
    console.log(array)
```

Comment: `map()` is designed to return a value, using `push` makes no sense. Did you ment to use a `forEach`?

Comment: Yes forEach is more suitable.

Comment: Thanks. Sort of worked but it was still an object of arrays as below.  [["bulldog"],["labrador"],["beagle"],["dobermann"]]